# SwiftUI How to make a slide in view that pushes another view away while keeping it the same size

Tags: swiftui

[Before Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0z4l.png)
[After Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk4HU.png)

```
struct SlideView: View {
        @State var isClicked = false
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .frame(width: isClicked ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75 : 0)
                
                
            VStack{
                Text("This gets squished")
                HStack{
                    Button{
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            isClicked.toggle()
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "menucard.fill")
                            .padding(.leading)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So I have this view that kind of "slides in" and it's pretty close to what I want but not exactly, the view that slides in ends up squishing the other view and compressing it to be about 25% of it's size. Of course this makes sense because it's all in a HStack and I end up taking 75% of the HStack's space but I was wondering if anybody had an idea of how I could do something like this but without squishing the second view that gets pushed away? So basically keep it the same size and just have the first 1/4 of the view visible and the other 3/4 just be gone I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the view that gets squished has no explicit width. Understand how views get sized in SwiftUI. The parent view proposes a size, and the child view responds with the size it wants. Before you click the button, the parent view (the `HStack`) is proposing 100% to the view. That view says that I can do 100%, so no squishing. However, when you make the other view 75% of the parent, the parent can only offer 25% to the first view. The view responds, I can fit if I squish, so it does. [See Laying out a simple view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/laying-out-a-simple-view).

To fix it, you simply need to explicitly set the width of the first view to 100%, and then it will get pushed over like you were expecting without compression.

```
struct SlideInView: View {
    @State var isClicked = false
    var body: some View {
        // I swapped out UIScreen.main.bounds for a GeometryReader
        // UIScreen.main.bounds.width always returns the width of the screen
        // even if the parent view does not have that much space to offer, and
        // can lead to some interesting results.
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .frame(width: isClicked ? geometry.size.width * 0.75 : 0)
                
                VStack{
                    Text("This gets squished")
                    HStack{
                        Button{
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                isClicked.toggle()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "menucard.fill")
                                .padding(.leading)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width) // Explicitly set width here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiny problem with this is I also have a toggle in the view that slides in and it seems that when a view with a toggle inside it has a frame with zero width the toggle still stays there? Is that on purpose or what?

Comment: I was able to fix this by just adding some binding into the slide view for when the settings are turned on, and only showing the toggle if settings are turned on but that seems a little weird to me idk if I should be doing something like that.

Comment: You could use the `isClicked` variable to control that. I suspect that is a bug. Are you on 16? If so, it would be worth filing a feedback.

Comment: Nope I'm on iOS 15

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it would make more sense to just use `.offset`, and put them in a `ZStack`:

```swift
ZStack {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("yellow")
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .background(.yellow)
    
    VStack {
        Text("red")
        HStack {
            Button{
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    isClicked.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "menucard.fill")
                    .padding(.leading)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .background(.red)
    .offset(.init(width: isClicked ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75 : 0, height: 0))
}
```

And you can add another `.offset` modifier to the yellow one to make it looks slidein:

```swift
VStack {
  //...
}
.background(.yellow)
.offset(.init(width: isClicked ? 0 : -UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75, height: 0))
```